# DropDownButton arrow not expanded

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to expand Two DropDownButtons in a row to fill up the space. The buttons get expanded but the arrow doesn't expand. Is there a way to make this work properly? Can't seem to find any solution so far.

This is my sample Code:

```
body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    isDense: true,
                    items: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March'].map((month) => DropdownMenuItem<String>( child: Text(month),)).toList(),
                    onChanged: (month){
                          print(month);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    items: ['1', '2', '3'].map((day) => DropdownMenuItem<String>( child: Text(day),)).toList(),
                    onChanged: (day){
                          print(day);
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

This is the current view:
[image: DropdownButton with arrow not expanded]

Comment: try to add width for your text SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-50,child: Text(month),)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shyjuzz/06ab36dcdf559432ee124e5a54026602

Comment: Thank @ShyjuM. That is a nice hack that i can use for now.